# NodeJs with Express not parsing form data from node-fetch

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, multipartform-data

I'm creating two APIs with NodeJS, Express, and TypeScript. One API will take a request with a content type of `multipart/form-data`, and will use the body in the request to make another request to a second API.

I'm using Postman, so the chain of request looks something like this

```
Postman -> First API -> Second API
```

I use `node-fetch` to make a request from the first API to the second one. The body of the request is a `FormData`, which contains some files and key-value pairs.

```
    const form = new FormData();
    
    // File for profile picture
    const profilePictureBuffer = await (await fetch(user.profilePicture)).buffer();
    form.append('profilePicture', profilePictureBuffer);

    // File for ID Card
    const idCardBuffer = await (await fetch(user.idCardUrl)).buffer();
    form.append('idCard', idCardBuffer);


    // This part iterats over the obsect of 'user',
    // which contains other key-value pairs
    Object.entries(user).forEach((data) => {
        form.append(data[0], data[1]);
    });

    // Make POST request to second API
    const pinterUser = await fetch(secondAPIURL, {
        method: 'post',
        body: form,
        headers: form.getHeaders()
    });
```

I ran both of the APIs on localhost so that I can monitor the logs for any bugs. As I make a request from Postman to the first API, then the first API make another request to the second API, I got the following error log in the terminal for the second API

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

After some investigation, **I found out that, in the second API, the `req.body` and `req.files` are empty objects**. This means that Express did not parse the incoming request. Note that I've also already a `multer` middleware to handle the files in the request.

Furthermore, I have added the following lines of code in my `server.ts` file for the second API

```
/** Parse the body of the request */
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(express.json());
```

**However, when I tried making the request from Postman, it returns a successful response.**

I'm not really sure what's going on here. I've tried looking for some answer regarding this similar issue, but most of them suggest adding `urlencoded` and `json`, or using some other library to handle parsing form data.

In my case, the first suggestion doesn't solve my problem since I already added them from the start, and the latter is what I'm trying to avoid.

I wonder if anybody could point out what I was missing here? Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks OK at a glance. Try using network debugging tools like wireshark (if running on plain HTTP), or point the client in the first API at a listening `netcat` instance, which will print anything it gets over TCP. See what the first API is really sending to the second API and go from there.